# place a "?" after function name to know more about function

Tags: python

Textbook says "To learn more about a function, place a ? after its name. For example, typing math.log? will bring up a description of the log function in the math module."

I've tried to implement this example in Jupyter Notebook but got an error. Why?

```
import math
math.log?
        ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Where is that quoted instruction from?

Comment: Try in `ipython` shell. It works

Comment: you shoud call Python built-in function `help` as `help(math.log)` to learn about that method

Comment: thank you@ArtyomVancyan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `__doc__` to get the docstring of a function:

With ?:

```
math.log?
```

Output:

```
Docstring:
log(x[, base])

Return the logarithm of x to the given base.
If the base not specified, returns the natural logarithm (base e) of x.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

With `__doc__`:

```
math.log.__doc__
```

Output:

```
log(x[, base])\n\nReturn the logarithm of x to the given base.\nIf the base not specified, returns the natural logarithm (base e) of x.
```

Answer (score 0):

It works now. Because the output pops out in a separate box in Jupyter Notebook so I didn't' notice it.